# $d_1(x,y)=|x-y|$ & $d_2(x,y)=|\frac1x-\frac1y|$ inducing same topology on $[1,\infty)$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

My textbook says the following: Let $X=[1,\infty)$ and define $d_1(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $d_2(x,y)=|\frac1x-\frac1y|$ . Then $d_1$ and $d_2$ are inducing the same topology, $(X,d_1)$ is complete but $(X,d_2)$ isn't.

So I want to verify this: I know the induced topology is defined by 
$$
A\in\tau\iff\forall x\in A\exists r>0:B_r^d(x)\subset A
$$with $B_r^d(x)=\{y\in X:d(x,y)<r\}$.

Clearly, we have $B_r^{d_1}(x)\subset B_r^{d_2}(x)$ for all $x\in X$ and therefore $$
A\in\tau_{d_2}\implies A\in\tau_{d_1}
$$
How do you get the other way around? And are we done then?

Comment: "Clearly, we have $B_r^{d_2}(x)\subset B_r^{d_1}(x)$ for all $x\in X$" Sure about that?

Comment: @Did well I thought $|\frac1x-\frac1y|=\frac{|x-y|}{xy}\leq |x-y|$ since $x,y\geq1$.

Comment: Indeed -- and? $ $

Comment: if $|x-y|<r$, then $|\frac1x-\frac1y|<r$... I don't get it at the moment - did I switch the balls?

Comment: Indeed you did switch. No big deal.